# Open a list of popovers - react

Tags: reactjs, popover

I have an element that has a Popover.
My Popover components gets a ref and know how to position itself:

```
const ref = useRef();

<div ref={ref}>Element</div>
<Popover targetRef={ref} >Popover element </Popover>
```

Now, I want to add a second Popover that will open under the first one:
[image]

Which ref I need to give to the second Popover? How can I achieve this behavior?